# SignedGlobalID case-insensitive & shorter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to use the globalid gem and it's `SignedGlobalID` to obfuscate the underlying model of an ID and it's integer value, see https://github.com/rails/globalid#signed-global-ids

To make them stable (e.g. return the same value every time you encode it), you just have to pass `expires_in: nil` as an option, or overwrite Rails 1 month default: `Rails.application.config.global_id.expires_in = nil`

```
[21] pry(main)> Product.first.to_sgid(expires_in: nil).to_s
=> "BAh7CEkiCGdpZAY6BkVUSSIvZ2lkOi8vYXRhbGFuZGEvU3ByZWU6OlByb2R1Y3QvMT9leHBpcmVzX2luBjsAVEkiDHB1cnBvc2UGOwBUSSIMZGVmYXVsdAY7AFRJIg9leHBpcmVzX2F0BjsAVDA=--4e0d93aac0791f40d1bf66103dc096087c0a297f"
```

Alas, there are some drawbacks:

1. When you give out those IDs and use it in 3rd party contexts, e.g. to identify resources (think of external partners, Google Merchant, Facebook Catalog), **they often treat the identifier case-insensitive**. So from time to time you get back a downcased version of those identifiers (from a response, some manual export from a customer...) they don't work anymore:

```
[25] pry(main)> GlobalID::Locator.locate_signed "bah7cekicgdpzay6bkvussivz2lkoi8vyxrhbgfuzgevu3byzwu6olbyb2r1y3qvmt9lehbpcmvzx2lubjsavekidhb1cnbvc2ugowbussimzgvmyxvsday7afrjig9lehbpcmvzx2f0bjsavda=--4e0d93aac0791f40d1bf66103dc096087c0a297f"
=> nil
```

2. **190 characters are sometimes too long for some systems.** You want to export into an external system and use your public, stable identifier, but they say the maximal length is 100 characters. Or 60. Or 32...

Does anyone have an idea, how to mitigate these drawbacks? Is there a way to use globalid case insensitive? And is there any way to shorten them? I like the idea of using something that belongs to the Rails core (I guess one can expect that it's going to be maintained for a longer time than some gem).

Comment: With don't you just add a unique UUID to each record? Or use UUIDs as your primary `id` per default?

Comment: Using signed global ids like this is a bad idea since the id contains the class name of your models. That means that you're hard coupling the *external resource* to your models which are an internal implementation detail. KISS and use a UUID.

Comment: Stuffing a bunch of references to the class name into your database is also bad enough when its in cleartext like with STI and polymorphic assocations. If you used signed globalids in there you're setting yourself up for a lot of pain if you ever need to refactor. I honestly can't really see any advantages to this approach.

Comment: The general arguments against UUIDs for PKs only become applicable with ultra massive datasets but anyone truly using datasets of that size can afford to mitigate those problems via other means. Use UUID.